# Undefined issue when comparing two JSON files

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

**test.json**

```
{"discountPriceValues":[[{"Price":"0.0"},{"Scode":"S0375102"}],[{"Price":"2.0"},{"Scode":"s0779548"}]],"isEmployeeOJ":"Y"}
```

**app.js**

```
var test = $http.get("data/test.json").then(function (response5) {
  $scope.testing = response5.data;
  return response5;
});
test.then(function(testing){
    $scope.testing = testing.data.discountPriceValues;
}); 

for(var x = 0; x < $scope.callplanList.length; x++){
  for(var t = 0; t < $scope.testing.length; t++ ){
                        console.log($scope.testing[t].Scode);
                            if($scope.callplanList[x].s_code == $scope.testing[t].Scode){
                                console.log($scope.testing[t]);
                            }
                    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="description">
<p>Test</p>
</div>
```

I need to check the scodes of callplans.json and test.json, if any common values are available then I need to enable a div in HTML. But I'm getting undefined in the console for this code - console.log($scope.testing[t].Scode); and getting the correct values as 2 for $scope.testing.length;

Any help would be appreciated

Note: I'm not attaching the other JSON files and code because for this functionality those are not required.

Comment: Where is `$scope.callplanList` defined ?

Comment: var planReq = $http.get("data/callplans.json").then(function (response1) {
      $scope.callplanList = response1.data;
   return response1;
 });

Comment: and then calling into a variable

Comment: Try `$scope.testing[t][1].Scode`.

Comment: your for loop is outside callback passed to `then` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that your `json` object contains nested arrays.

As I said in comments, just change to `$scope.testing[t][1].Scode`, because you have nested arrays.

I suggest to use `filter` method in order to check if you have common values.

```
let callplanListCodes = $scope.callplanList.map(a=>a[1].Scode);
let testingCodes = $scope.testing.map(a=>a[1].s_code;
$scope.hasCommon = callplanListCodes .filter((n) => testingCodes .includes(n))
```

HTML

```
<div ng-if="hasCommon" class="description">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mihai, Thanks for the reply. and how to enable the <div> only if the condition satisfies.

Comment: @user3774781, just use `ng-if` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Since the format of your data is weird, that would have to be:

```
console.log($scope.testing[t][1].Scode);
```

See also the snippet below.

```js
const data = {
  "discountPriceValues": [
    [{
      "Price": "0.0"
    }, {
      "Scode": "S0375102"
    }],
    [{
      "Price": "2.0"
    }, {
      "Scode": "s0779548"
    }]
  ],
  "isEmployeeOJ": "Y"
};


for (var t = 0; t < data.discountPriceValues.length; t++) {
  console.log(data.discountPriceValues[t][1].Scode);
}
```